# Missing privileges for dashboard access

Tags: xcode, icloud

Got this error when clicked "CloudKit Dashboard".

[image]

I've

- enabled the iCloud in xcode
- created an iCloud container
- enabled the iCloud in App ID

[image]

How can I solve this?